# Problems with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined, intervals

I am just trying to implement the most basic example of setInterval with jQuery and am having problems. What's wrong here?

It says function rotate is not defined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = 5000;
    var run = setInterval("rotate()", speed);

    function rotate() {
        alert ('rotate');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = 5000;

    function rotate() {
        alert ('rotate');
    }

    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
});
```

You could also simply do this:

```
$(function() {
    var speed = 5000;

    var run = setInterval(function() {
        alert ('rotate');
    }, speed);
});
```

You should declare `run` outside the ready event handler if you wish to be able to clear the interval later though, since it will go out of scope otherwise.

Comment: @mheavers: notice that i put the function declaration above the setInterval - you cannot use a reference to function that is not yet defined.

Comment: that's untrue. It's true in the original example because the code is getting evalled, but thanks to [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), rotate is defined and run perfectly correctly anywhere in that scope.

Comment: @Simon: You are of course completely right, thanks for the great link :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `setInterval` a string to eval. This is:

- Hard to debug
- Inefficient
- Ugly
- **executed in a different scope**

The function is limited in scope to the function it is defined inside.

Pass the function directly instead

```
    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
```

Answer (score 1):

omit the parenthesis and quotes around rotate in your setInterval call. You are giving it the function itself, not the name. It shouldn't matter the order that they go in.

Answer (score 1):

That's effectively eval-ing rotate in (what I believe is) its own context. Change it to

```
var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

or even put the rotate function outside the ready function.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function rotate() {
        alert ('rotate');
    }
    var speed = 5000;
    var run = setInterval(function() { rotate() }, speed);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `rotate` in the global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.rotate = function() {
        alert ('rotate');
    }
    var speed = 5000;
    var run = setInterval("rotate()", speed);
});
```

Comment: But yeah, like the others said - this is ugly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   var speed = 5000;
   var rotate = function() {
      alert("rotate");
   };

   window.setInterval(rotate, speed);
});
```